# .Net Access Global Variable In Server Include from Master Page

Tags: .net, variables, include, master-pages

I want to have the Date as a global variable that a server included aspx can access. I have a handful of master templates, but I want the header and the footer to be a server include so that I just have one place to update links instead of having them in each of the masters. In the footer, I want the copyright date to be dynamic and hopefully make that a global variable that can be accessed elsewhere.

I tried putting it in the master page and also the server include in a server script in the aspx, but I haven't been able to get either working. I get that the error that the variable does not exist in the context. I tried declaring and registering the namespace, but I must be doing something wrong.

I want to get the variable currentYear from the Master Page Code into the footer.aspx (include).

Master Page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="OneColumn.master.cs" Inherits="Project.Masters.OneColumn" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head id="oneColumnHead" runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<form id="oneColumnForm" runat="server">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="body" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</form>
    <%-- Shared Footer --%>
    <!-- #Include file="inc_footer.aspx" -->

</body>
</html>
```

Master Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Project.Masters
{
    public partial class OneColumn : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {

        static int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Footer Aspx

```
<div id="footer">Copyright © <%= currentYear %></div>
```

So the footer just contains the HTML to be included. How do I register that master page in the footer include?

EDIT: OK so it is not possible. I am trying the User Control method. That is not working either.

This is what I have.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Project.Masters
    {
    public partial class uc_footer : System.Web.UI.UserControl
        {
        static int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
        string dateYear = currentYear.ToString();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

The ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="uc_footer.ascx.cs" Inherits="TeamWork.Masters.uc_footer" %>
<div id="footer">Copyright © <%= dateYear %></div>
```

It still says it does not exist in context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it something like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="OneColumn.master.cs"
  Inherits="Project.Masters.OneColumn" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="footer" Src="~/PATHTOYOURCONTROL" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head id="oneColumnHead" runat="server">
    <title>Master page title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="oneColumnForm" runat="server">
        <table>
           <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="body" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <uc:footer id="footer1" runat="server"/>
                </td>
            <tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbz9etab.aspx) how to include a control to the page

Comment: I need for it to be in the server include footer file. I'm wanting to make that include file a one stop shop for all of the templates. The actual footer file is much more complex than this simple example. It has all sorts of links and things. I only want to edit that in one place, and not 10-20 master templates.

Comment: I saw there was some way to do a Register @ (Master(Project)) something or other to access that global variable from the master template, but I have not been able to get that to work.

Comment: If you have a complex footer. Make a usercontrol of it and then replace it with the `div`.

Comment: I'm sure there has to be an easier solution than that. I have to believe there is a way to register and connect the master page and this included file. OR to make the included file have the variable in its own code behind.

Comment: It looks like Server.Execute might work instead of the include. Apparently, dynamic includes are not possible since they are not processed when they included. So, my variable does not exist when it is added to the master.

Comment: OK, you were right, a user control is the way to go, but I still can't get it. I edited my post above. Can you see what is wrong?

Comment: Thanks. And the other issue was that the string var also had to be public even though my static var was in the same control. static int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;     public string dateYear = currentYear.ToString();

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a similar question to this before:

[VS 2005 fails to build aspx files with includes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467361/vs-2005-fails-to-build-aspx-files-with-includes/9472198#9472198)

Server Side Includes are done by IIS and not asp.net.  So the include you're trying to do with the footer would be included too late in the game for it to work.  The include will not have any idea about the controls or variables contained in your file.

I would recommend using a user control to avoid duplicating code as mentioned in other answers.  Also, you may want to consider throwing the copyright date into the web.config or a static application-wide variable if you only want it set once.